# condition checking in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a block of terraform code.

```
data "am_nodes" "tm_nodes" {
  count          = length(local.l_domains)
  ay             = local.l_domains[count.index].name
  pol           = local.am_pool[count.index].resource_id
  host_reg = "${local.reg_k}${local.cte_env_map[local.environment]}-pd${local.pI}-mr*"
}
```

here I want to put a condition like if local.pI value is 0 then ignore entire host_reg
is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with the ternary operator, like this:

```
data "am_nodes" "mt_nodes" {
  count         = length(local.l_domains)
  ay            = local.l_domains[count.index].name
  pol           = local.am_pool[count.index].resource_id
  host_reg = local.pl == 0 ? null : "${local.reg_k}${local.cte_env_map[local.environment]}-dp${local.pI}-mr*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so here it would be like if the local.pl value stands 0 then host_reg will be completely ignored or value of 0 will be assigned to it?

Comment: in case `local.pl` is `0`, the `host_reg` will get `null` as the value.